# Click on a button inside a dialog which is pop-up from a gridview when i click a item.And this gridview is inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-fragments, android-dialog

How can i click on a button inside a dialog which is pop-up from a gridview when i click a item.And this gridview is inside a fragment ?

It does not allow me to creat onclicklistener for this ok button.
error hint:
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

Here is my code :

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DiningFragment extends Fragment{


    GridView gridView;
    TextView Details1;
    TextView Details2;
    static final String[] NAMES = new String[] { "aroma", "aura", "crave",
            "urbanbean", "flava", "map" };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dining, container,
                false);


        Details1 = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.dining_details1);
        Details2 = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.dining_details2);
        gridView = (GridView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        gridView.setAdapter(new DiningAdapter(getActivity(), NAMES));

        String textLinks1 = "tesetestsetest";
        String textLinks2 = "testtest";

        if (Details1 != null) {
            // set text to text view
            Details1.setText(textLinks1);

            Linkify.addLinks(Details1, Linkify.ALL); // linkify all links in
                                                        // text.
            // you can set link color with the help of text view property
            Details1.setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
        if (Details2 != null) {
            // set text to text view
            Details2.setText(textLinks2);

            Linkify.addLinks(Details2, Linkify.ALL); // linkify all links in
                                                        // text.
            // you can set link color with the help of text view property
            Details2.setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        }

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {




                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dining_label))
                                .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();







                **//  dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dining_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dining_dialogtext);
                text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dining_dialogimage);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dining_dialogButtonOK);


                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                dialog.show();**









            }
        });

        return inflatedView;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OnClickListener that my implement is not correct, try to implement View.OnClickListener and not DialogInterface.OnClickListener.

use import

import View.OnClickListener

instead of

import DialogInterface.OnClickListener